# Set the height of a child div to parents height - siblings height

Tags: css, html, height

I have 2 child divs within a parent div. Child1 is the header and Child2 is the body. I want the height of Child 2 to be set to height of Parent - Child1. Child2 has content so it should be scrollable

I know I can set the height for Child2 via JS, but is it poss to do this via CSS?

Comment: I could make the headers(Child1) height fixed, yes.

Comment: Also, where's your code? What have you tried so far? You can't perform calculations within CSS without the use of Javascript, so you can't do something like `c2.height = parent.height - c1.height`.

Comment: (SASS/LESS doesn't count, either, as it has to be compiled externally (though something like SimpLESS) or with the help of a LESS.js script.)

Comment: Mark-down is just for general lack of code/description of what you've tried. James' answer is a good one, but it's hard to tell if there are other factors that might have to be accounted for, just from what little description you provided.

Comment: @mori57 Well, I didn't know of a way of doing this, so there was no way I could provide examples of what I've tried. The only code I could provide would have been for the HTML mark-up, which is pretty straight forward. I also mentioned that I know of a way to do this in JS but I'm looking for a CSS solution, so it was no use giving the JS code out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the height is fixed you can simply give the header negative `margin-bottom` equal to the height of the header, then give the content divider `padding-top` also equal to that height:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { height:100%; margin:0; }
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
}
#header {
    height:100px; /* Fixed height header */
    margin-bottom:-100px; /* Negative height of header */
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
}
#content {
    min-height:100%;
    padding-top:100px; /* Height of header */
    box-sizing:border-box;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6N7yD/3/).

Comment: Why use all that stuff with position:relative? This seems to work just as well, in Chrome ... does position: relative fix issues with the technique in other browsers? http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/uBHz2/

Comment: It's for `z-index`. Yours results in scrolling when the content doesn't fill the page: http://jsfiddle.net/uBHz2/1/

Comment: Thanks, @JamesDonnelly. I'm in the process of trying this out. Another thing is that I want only Child2 to scroll and not the parent, since only the content for Child2 overflows. Any pointers towards achieving thaT?

Comment: That is PERFECT! Thank-you @JamesDonnelly, been trying to do this for a few hours now!